# converting PDF to JPEG on AWS Lambda

Tags: compilation, aws-lambda, poppler

I've written a small lambda Python function that makes use of [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) to convert a PDF file's pages into separate JPG files. This library is a wrapper around `poppler-utils`, in particular `pdftoppm`. Works fine on my Ubuntu system, but of course AWS Lambda is different.

So I went to look for a version of poppler that I could compile on an EC2 instance for AWS Lambda and found the slightly dated [Poppler-build](https://github.com/outlandishideas/poppler-build) ansible playbook. With some tweaks, I got it to work, however the Poppler version this playbook builds does not include the essential `-jpeg` flag which turns ppms data straight into jpegs.

I tried compiling newer versions of Poppler but they all seem to involve libraries and C++ versions that I'd have to install separately and I worry that this will break AWS Lambda support.

Poppler 0.58 always balks at

> make[3]: Entering directory
>   `/home/ec2-user/poppler3/poppler-0.58.0/poppler'   CXX
>   libpoppler_la-SignatureInfo.lo In file included from
>   SignatureInfo.cc:22:0: /usr/include/nss3/hasht.h:48:29: error:
>   ‘PRBool’ has not been declared
>        void (*destroy)(void *, PRBool);

Poppler 0.69 (latest) on the other hand gets antsy about:

> /home/ec2-user/poppler2/poppler-0.69.0/poppler/Annot.cc: In
>   constructor ‘DefaultAppearance::DefaultAppearance(GooString*)’:
>   /home/ec2-user/poppler2/poppler-0.69.0/poppler/Annot.cc:826:23: error:
>   ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’
>              fontColor = std::make_unique(gatof(( (GooString *)daToks->get(i-1) )->getCString()));
>                          ^ /home/ec2-user/poppler2/poppler-0.69.0/poppler/Annot.cc:826:50: error:
>   expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>              fontColor = std::make_unique(gatof(( (GooString *)daToks->get(i-1) )->getCString()));

This endless trying to compile libraries and configuring with various flags and compilers etc has taken me over two days now and I'm ready to give up. Is there a chance someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, or suggest another efficient way to turn PDF pages into JPEG files on AWS Lambda?

Comment: have you resolved the issue. Can you please post the build if you have succeeded.

Comment: I've not really found a solution that uses poppler. I mean I think I got it working but something else produced issues so I ended up calling `convert` through Popen since imagemagick is available. It seems slower than Poppler, though. If you find a solution, I'd be happy to hear it.